# Using custom ticks with RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I'm trying to change to plot a sphere using `RegionPlot3D` and look at how the shape of the sphere changes when you use a logarithmic scale (or any nonlinear scale) for the x, y, and z axes. The code to produce a sphere on linear axes is:

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 90]
```

This works fine, but I cannot seem to change the axes to a nonlinear scale. The CustomTicks package seems to be a good start, but I cannot seem to make it work for `RegionPlot3D`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: It is not clear how you imagine to take the logarithm of the negative coordinates, say, in terms of  `x ` from -1 to 0?

Answer (score 3):

Logarithmic transformation is not a good idea, since the coordinates are varying partially in the negative domain, as I mentioned above. One can do this with the positive part of the sphere, if you like:

```
 RegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + Exp[y]^2 + z^2 < 4, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 0, Log[2]}, {z, 1, 2}, 
 Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 90, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3], 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

where I only transformed the coordinate y. It should look as follows:
[image]

Have fun!